# Grid Inside Bootstrap Responsive NavBar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, navbar

I need your help here. I am trying to use Bootstrap grid system within the NBootstrap NavBar. The problem is when I use the Grid within the NavBar, the NavBar becomes non-responsive, meaning, on a reduced viewport the NavBar toggle no longer works if the grid has been used within NavBar.

```
body
    .container-fluid
        .container
            nav.navbar.navbar-toggleable-md.navbar-light.bg-faded.row
                button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right(type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
                    span.navbar-toggler-icon
                .navbar-brand.col-lg-3
                    img(src='img/main-logo.svg' height='60')
                .collapse.navbar-collapse#navbarSupportedContent.justify-content-end.col-lg-9
                    ul.navbar-nav.ul-extension.nav-fill
                        li.nav-item.active
                            a.nav-link(href="#") Home
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') About
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') Services
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') Gallery
                        li.nav-item
                            a.nav-link(href='#') Contact
```

Comment: Post the code please

Comment: added the code.